# Making a bitbucket source wiki from javadocs

Tags: java, markdown, javadoc, bitbucket, doclet

Hi i am working on pretty big internal SDK that we use for our apps. I have outfitted with extensive Javadocs. Now my goal is to somehow generate .MD files from these javadocs so that i can directly put these .md files into my bitbucket wiki.

Is there a way to this or to generate any other file format that bitbucket wiki can work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) appears to [support Javadoc-style comments](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) and can [output LaTeX](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html). LaTeX can be consumed by [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which supports Markdown output. This is somewhat roundabout, but it's the only realistic option that I can see.

Something like the following (untested)

```
# Generate a Doxygen configuration file, which
# should enable LaTeX output by default
doxygen -g

# Generate LaTeX documentation in the latex/ directory
doxygen

# Generate one Markdown file for each LaTeX file
find latex/ -name '*.tex' -exec mkdir -p markdown/`dirname {}` && \
    pandoc -o markdown/`basename {} .pdf`.md {} \;
```

should get you close.

The alternative might be to take Javadoc-generated HTML and ingest that with Pandoc, outputting Markdown.